# Get values from nested stdClass objects, and search sql data type smalldatetime

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to php and sql, and I'm trying to pull a value out of an object or a nested object.  I'm able to see the code when i use the print_r command, but i'm unable to separate the actual date from the oject, and I'm also not able to search the sql using the datetime criteria. I do know that the "Date" is stored in sql as a smalldatetime data type, and I don't know how to work with that.

when i try to search sql using the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM GL_Register WHERE (Register_Id='5' && Date='2010-12-8 0:00:00')";
```

I get the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '&'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '&'. ) )

So i cannot pull a query with the date in there properly because i don't know how.  to further clarify, i am able to pull information from the database using the following information, but i am still unable to pull out the date from within the Date object.

here's how i'm loading the object:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM GL_Register WHERE Register_Id='3'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
else{
    echo $sql;
}

while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)) {
   $count++;
   $row = '<tr>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$count.'</td>';
   //$row .= '<td>'.$obj->Date->DateTime->date.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$obj->Account_Id.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$obj->Customer_Id.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$obj->Category_Id.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$obj->Credit_Or_Debit.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>'.$obj->Memo.'</td>';
   $row .= '<td>$'.$obj->Amount.'</td>';
   $row .= '</tr>';
   echo "$row";
}
```

when i use the "print_r($obj)", this is what it displays:

> stdClass Object ( [Register_Id] => 3 [Account_Id] => 5 [Register_Number] => 17 [Credit_Or_Debit] => D [Accounting_Period_Id] => 13 [Date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2010-12-21 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => MST ) [Register_Type_Id] => 1 [Reference] => 300002 [Type_CVEO] => C [Customer_Id] => 362 [Vendor_Id] => 1 [Employee_Id] => 1 [Other_Name] => [Offset_Account_Id] => 1 [Splits] => N [Amount] => 179.9600 [Mult_Sign] => 1 [Memo] => Security Services [Status] => O [Is_Offset] => N [Offset_Register_Id] => 4 [Branch_Id] => 2 [Job_Id] => 1 [Service_Ticket_Id] => 1 [Category_Id] => 6 [Job_Expense_Code] => [Expense_Type_Id] => 5 [Post_WIP_Account_Id] => 1 [Primary_Register_Number] => 0 [Part_Id] => 1 [Currency_Id] => 1 [Exchange_Rate] => 1.0000 [Amount_Nat] => 179.9600 [Date_Time_Stamp] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2010-12-21 12:29:06 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => MST ) )

I need to be able to do two things, and i feel like i'm banging my head against the wall.  It's just out of my reach and i'm hoping someone can help me out.

Questions:

- How to fix the sql query using the the datetime criteria (ie pull all register_id's that have a date within the last 3 days)?
- How to pull the date and time out of the object and place it into a php variable

Comment: replace && with `and`

Answer (score 0):

use AND instead of &&

```
SELECT * FROM GL_Register WHERE Register_Id='5' AND Date='2010-12-8 0:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that i was using the wrong operators. I tried this, and it still doesn't work.  i even tried just looking using "Date" instead of Register_Id, and nothing would pull up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with the help of a friend and chetan above, i was able to answer the first question.  my first problem was that i had the wrong operators in the question.  my second problem, was i was formatting the date wrong.  the date needed to be formatted one of the following two ways:

```
select * from GL_Register where Date = '07/01/2013'
```

or

```
select * from GL_Register where Date = {d'2013-07-01'}
```

The first method uses an implicit conversion from varchar to date. The order of the date IE 'mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy' is controlled by your local settings.The second method is more proper as the {d} specifies that the varchar is to be converted to a date and is not dependent on your date format settings.

but i still need the answer to the second question, how do i print the date out on a datetime object?

Answer (score 0):

answered the second question.  since the sql was outputting data in the DateTime format, i needed to create a new DateTime variable and dump the information into that object.  once i did that,  i was able to format the data ho i needed to and use it accordingly.

```
$newDate = new DateTime('NOW');
while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) {
$newDate = $obj->Date->format('Y-m-d');
```

This outputs the date in the format i need.